# Xamarin.Essentials "The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class."

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My application gives an error:

> The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class.

I use the emulator Genymotion. GPS enabled

```
public async Task btnAdd_Click()
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

            if (location != null)
            {
                string note = "GPS: Latitude-" + location.Latitude + " Longitude-" + location.Longitude;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Unable to get location
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you follow step 5 of the install docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=macos%2Candroid#installation

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like the error states, did you add this line:

```
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
```

In your `MainActivity.cs` in the `OnCreate` method?

Comment: I had the same issue, and also had to override the `OnRequestPermissionsResult` method on all Android activities


`public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}`


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=windows%2Candroid#installation

Comment: Maui wants `base.OnCreate` to be called from within the override.

Answer (score 4):

Improve Gerald answer by offer full code

```
    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        txtnumber = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        txtnumber.Text ="Initializing";



        try
        {

            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
            txtnumber.Text = "finish read geolocation";


            if (location != null)
            {
                txtnumber.Text = "GPS: Latitude-" + location.Latitude + " Longitude-" + location.Longitude;
            }
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            // Handle not supported on device exception
        }
        catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
        {
            // Handle not enabled on device exception
        }
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {
            // Handle permission exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Unable to get location
            txtnumber.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need init Xamarin Essentials in OnCreate function from MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    ...
}
```

Then overide the function should work

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
```

and in the `MainActivity.cs` file, `OnCreate` Method, insert:

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code snipper with the tool provided.