# 'The active Window can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Application class.'

Tags: .net, maui

I am trying to add files using file picker in .net MAUI I am getting error while adding files.
I am getting error on that await line. I tried to add oncreate method in maiacticity.cs file but it is showing same exception.
This is my Model:

```
public class Data
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return fileName; }
        set { fileName = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Item 
{
    ObservableCollection<Data> result = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    [RelayCommand]
    public async void Add_File()
    {
        var CustomFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<String>>
    {
        {
                DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] {"pdf"}
        },
    });
        var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            FileTypes = CustomFileType,
        });
        foreach (var fileResult in results)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileResult.FullPath);
            bool fileExist = false;
            foreach(Data data in result)
            {
                fileExist = true;
                break;
            }
            if(!fileExist)
            {
                result.Add(new Data
                {
                    fileName = fileResult.FullPath,
                });
            }
            else
            {
                result = result;
            }
            
        }
        Datas=result;
                
    }
   public ObservableCollection<Data> Datas { get; private  set; }
    public Item()
    {
        Add_File();
    }
}
```

}
this is viewmodel:

```
 public Item Items;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<Data> data { get => Items.Datas; }
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Items = new Item();
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
this is where I am trying to bind that data 
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label 
        Text="Hello from child view"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Text="{Binding fileName}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

I have main view where I have binded this child view. I have addfile button in my main view. If I am doing same code in code behind it is working fine. Even I have created same code in viewModel it is not showing any exception. I am not getting exact cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this function based on MVVM.

You can refer to the following code:

**Data.cs**

```
public class Data 
    {
        //public string filePath { get; set; }
        //public String FilePath
        //{
        //    get { return filePath; }
        //    set { filePath = value; }
        //}

        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

**PickFileViewModel.cs**

```
public class PickFileViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Data> Datas { get; set; }

        public ICommand PickDataCommand => new Command(addItemMethod);

        private void addItemMethod(object obj)
        {
            Add_File();
        }


        public PickFileViewModel()
        {
            Datas = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        }

        public async void Add_File()
        {
            var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
            {
                //FileTypes = customFileType
            });

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                bool fileExist = false;

                foreach (Data item in Datas)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        if (result.FileName.Equals(item.FileName))  // here I don't suggest compare `FilePath`,sometimes, if we select the same image, the FullPath maybe different  (result.FullPath.Equals(item.FilePath))
                        {
                            fileExist = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!fileExist)
                {
                    Datas.Add(new Data { FilePath = result.FullPath, FileName = result.FileName });
                }
            }

        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**PickFilePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.PickFilePage"
             Title="PickFilePage"
              xmlns:mauiapp="clr-namespace:MauiContentViewApp"
             >

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <mauiapp:PickFileViewModel></mauiapp:PickFileViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
        Text="Hello from child view"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button Text="Add file" Command="{Binding PickDataCommand}"></Button>

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**PickFilePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class PickFilePage : ContentPage 
{
      public PickFilePage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

Note:

1.please add permission in file AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2.I added two properties(`FilePath` and `FileName`) in model `Data`

```
public class Data 
{
    //public string filePath { get; set; }
    //public String FilePath
    //{
    //    get { return filePath; }
    //    set { filePath = value; }
    //}

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Please change to the corresponding property while binding:

```
  <Label Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
```

3.Here, I didn't create child `ContentView`. This way is simpler than creating child `ContentView`.
You can see my another way(creating child `ContentView`) here: [I want to bind data From two different views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74317026/i-want-to-bind-data-from-two-different-views/74440247#74440247) .

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided, and it runs without any errors.

I add the `addFile` method to `Button.Clicked` :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   private async void Button_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Monkey> result = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();
        try
        {
            var CustomFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<String>>
        {                
                {                    
                    DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[]{"ics"}
                },        
            });
            var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
                { FileTypes = CustomFileType, });
            foreach (var file in results)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.FullPath);
                //double size = fileSize(fileInfo);
                bool fileExist = false;
                foreach (Monkey item in result)
                {
                    if (item.fileName.Equals(file.FullPath))
                    {
                        fileExist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!fileExist)
                {
                    result.Add(new Monkey
                    {
                        fileName = file.FullPath,
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    //result = file.FullPath;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udtNJ.jpg).

I searched error message about "The active Window cannot be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Application class.", but little results about it. However, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800427/xamarin-essentials-the-current-activity-can-not-be-detected-ensure-that-you-ha). It could be helpful to you.

Comment: I don't want to add button click event I want to bind that through view model. And I tried to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800427/xamarin-essentials-the-current-activity-can-not-be-detected-ensure-that-you-ha this link. but it is not working.

Comment: Could you provide some more relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described.

Comment: I have updated my code @Jianwei sun